# RS-232 communication using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication, tcomport

Hi everyone I want to send/receive data serially via rs-232 using c#,VS10 ...
my code for do so is as follows .....

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
//predefined values are baud rate =9600, parity=none, databits=8,stopbit=1 
//for sending data I used a textbox same name itself and a button "sendbutton" which coded as follow
try
{
    sp.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
    textBox.Text = "";
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    baudRatelLabel.Text = ex.Message;
}
//for receiving data code is as follows 
try
{
    textBox.Text = "";
    textBox.Text = sp.ReadLine();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    baudRatelLabel.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

I installed this application in two pc and communicate both using using rs232 (both female end). But the data i'm sendig from one pc by send button is not received by another pc ....what should i do now.....

Comment: Are you using a Nullmodem cable?

Comment: Yaa I'm using Nullmodem cable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would do is use a different application to read the data. HyperTerminal, for example. Try to figure out if your app is sending or not, then, once you get it to send, work on trying to figure out if it is receiving data properly or not.

Comment: Thanx Joel ... but i heard about HyperTerminal but never used.Will you please send me a download link for same ...

Comment: Well, it's typically included in a windows install, so run the app and start learning about it. Typical exe location is: `C:\Program Files\Windows NT\hypertrm.exe`

Comment: Dosen't find hypertrm.exe at C:\Program Files\Windows NT\hypertrm.exe

Comment: Found a link to a trial version. Should be enough to get you going. http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal-trial/

Comment: PuTTY works, too. Hyperterminal is no longer included since XP SP3.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, that's funny, but only because I've used PuTTY for SSH connections over TCP/IP, and never tried to use it for serial.

Comment: @JoelRondeau: I didn't know at first either. Only when I found out that hyperterminal is no longer available on Windows 7 I had to look for alternatives.

Comment: TeraTerm is a nice alternative as well.

Comment: how to communicate my application with HyperTerminal ... nothing is going well ..... problem not solved .

Comment: Well, you can always start with 2 copies of HyperTerminal and confirm they can talk to each other. (@PreetSangha is eluding to concerns like this with his answer)

Answer (score 2):

Before you debug this. First rule of any hardware interation - you should verify that that the hardware and OS are correctly working. Both machines should be able to communicate to either other, or modems or other RS232 devices first. If the ports are all working properly, then you should try and debug your program using a know program on one side first.

I would use a comms program such as http://realterm.sourceforge.net/ as the know side.

I learned this lesson the hard way by spending 2 weeks debugging a program when there was dry joint in the cable!

Answer (score 0):

Call the `Open` method before trying to send anything. The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx) on the `Open` method even has sample code.

Comment: Hm. Then I'd go with Joel's answer and try to make only sending to the other PC work. Make sure you are using a twisted pair cable.